# Using chain rule to calculate a second-order partial derivative in spherical polar co-ordinates

Tags: evaluation, symbolic

I have a function $f$ and I am supposed to calculate its second-order partial derivative first in cartesian co-ordinates, which is fine. However, I am stuck while solving the problem in spherical coordinates.

Without worrying about the function $f$, how do I use chain-rule in Mathematica to express $\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}$ operation in spherical polar coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

I'm uncertain about what you are asking exactly, but you imply that you have a function `f[x,y,z]` that you have taken the second derivative wrt `x` such as `d2fdx2` and want to convert that to Spherical coordinates.

For that case it is a simple matter to convert your result by

```
cartValues = {x, y, z} ->  CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
    "Mapping", {r, θ, ϕ}] // Thread
(*{x -> r Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], y -> r Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], z -> r Cos[θ]}*)
```

Then use

```
d2fdx2/.cartValues
```

which will give your result in terms of `r, θ, ϕ`. Such a conversion does not involve the chain rule.  If, on the other hand you want to take the second derivative wrt `x` of `f[r, θ, ϕ]` it is a bit more involved, and does involve the chain rule.

First get some conversions.

```
sphValues = {r, θ, ϕ} -> 
   CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Spherical","Mapping", {x, y, z}] // Thread
(*{r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], θ -> ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ϕ -> ArcTan[x, y]}*)
```

and for later simplifications the reverse values:

```
reverseSphValues = {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] -> r, ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] -> θ, ArcTan[x, y] -> ϕ}
```

Take the second derivative of `f[r, θ, ϕ]` wrt `x`

```
d2xdx2 = D[f[r, θ, ϕ] /. sphValues, x, x] // Simplify
```

The results are in terms of `x,y,z` and are lengthy, so I won't print them out.
Some simplification.

```
d2xdx2 = d2xdx2 /. reverseSphValues
```

And further simplification.

```
d2xdx2 = d2xdx2 /. cartValues // Simplify[#, {r > 0, 0 <= θ <= π/2}] &
```

The result involves a long expression of trig functions and has may ways to simplify, so you might want to do your own manipulations.